# Is there any restrictions for channel's name of Parse Push notification?

Tags: android, parse-platform

My Parse Android SDK version is 1.8.0, I know I can subscribe to a channel by calling

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Ch1");
```

But there are many channel's names that I fail to subscribe (nothing happened after the function call.)

For example,

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("123");
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("1ab");
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Ch 0 (.)");
```

Is there any restrictions for channel's name of Parse Push notification or is it a bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question - **Yes**. There are restrictions for a valid channel name. From the docs

> The channel name must start with a letter and contain only letters,
>   numbers, dashes, and underscores.

[See here in documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html)